# Get back to root file PHP

Tags: php, braintree

Im writing this code:

```
require_once  'braintree/lib/Braintree.php';
```

And it doesn't work. I think its because I have the wrong directory. How do I get back to the root directory?

Comment: What dir are you in and what dir do you want to get to?

Comment: I have my the Braintree.php in a folder in my root folder

Comment: This assumes that in your current directory, you have a folder called `braintree` and has the subsequent structure. This is called using *relative paths*. You might want to use *absolute paths*  instead, perhaps by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - by printing that, and your current folder, `dirname(__FILE__)` you can find out which path you need to set.

Comment: Thanks @Qirel, that did it.